# Does the martingale property holds after changing filtration?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $\Omega$ be the space of continuous real-valued functions $\omega=(\omega_t)_{t\ge 0}$ starting at zero, i.e. $\omega_0=0$. Let $\Lambda=\Omega\times \mathbb R_+$ and denote by $\lambda=(\omega,\theta)$ its elements. Define by $\left(B=(B_t)_{t\ge 0},T\right)$ the canonical elements, i.e. $B(\lambda)=\omega$ and $T(\lambda)=\theta$. Define further the canonical filtration $\mathbb F=(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge 0}$, i.e. 
$$\mathcal F_t~:=~\sigma\left(B_s, \{T\le s\} \mbox{ for all } s\le t\right).$$
It is clear that $T$ is a $\mathbb F-$stopping time. Now let $\mathbb P$ be a probability measure on $(\Lambda, \mathcal F_{\infty})$ s.t. $B$ is a $\mathbb F-$Brownian motion under $\mathbb P$. Now, let $X$ be a gaussian random variable and $\varphi: \mathbb R\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a bounded measurable function. Denote by $\mathbb F^B=(\mathcal F^B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ the natural filtration generated by $B$, then it is clear that the process $Z_t:=E\left[\varphi(B_T,X)~|~\mathcal F^B_t\right]$ is a continuous martingale w.r.t. $\mathbb F^B$. My question is whether $Z=(Z_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is also a martingale w.r.t. to $\mathbb F$? Many thanks for the reply!

Comment: @ CodeGolf : Hi your definition of the canonical filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is not completely clear to me, could you elaborate on this point (for example exhibiting a simple set at fixed $t$ from $\mathcal{F}_t$). Best regards

Comment: We may write equally the filtration this way: Set $\mathcal F_t^T:=\sigma(\{T\le s\} \mbox{ for all } s\le t)$, then $\mathcal F_t=\mathcal F^B_t \vee \mathcal F^T_t$.

Comment: @ CodeGolf : Here my interpretation problem is on the set $\{T\le s\} $ which constitutes the "basis" for the sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}^T_t$ over the space $[0,t]$. What is the meaning of $\{T\le s\} $ in this context for a fixed $s leq t$?  Best regards

Comment: $\{T\le s\}$ stands for the subset $\{\lambda\in\Lambda: T(\lambda)\le s\}$.

Comment: @ Codegolf : Ok so as T is the canonical projection it means, unless mistaken, that $\{\lambda\in\Lambda: T(\lambda)\le s\}=[0,s]$ right ? Best regards.

Comment: Yes, $\{\lambda\in\Lambda: T(\lambda)\le s\}=\Omega\times [0,s]$

Comment: Hi if you can show that the filtration $\mathcal{F^B}$ can be seen a proper shrinkage of filtration (not totally clear but I think this is the case by using some simple trick like seeing $\Omega$ in one-to -one correspondence with $\Omega \times [0,t]$ for a fixed $t$), then Protter shows in his book (Lemma page 368 Chap VI) that in this case your process has to be a martingale (i.e. the optional projection of the original process on the shrank filtration, that means that you have to show that Z is this optional projection), hope this helps. Best regards

Comment: I shall read this paragraph. Thx a lot!

Comment: @CodeGofl : Giving second thought about your problem this is not a filtration shrinkage as I first thought, neither it is a classical enlargement  of filtration as it is more an enlargement of the probability basis. I still think it might be true but it is a bit more involved that I thought. Best regards.